# r data.table - compare columns with same suffix

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have pair of variables with the same suffix and would like to compare and generate Y or N flag. I can type conditions one by one but just wondering if there is a better way to do using apply function.

I would prefer a solution using data.table package.

```
x <- data.table(x_abc="A1", y_abc="A1", x_pqr="A1", y_pqr="B1")
x[,':='(abc=ifelse(x_abc==y_abc,"Y","N"), pqr=ifelse(x_pqr==y_pqr,"Y","N"))]
```

Comment: Is this a small example that represents a much larget data set with multiple columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create 2 vectors of column names and compare them in parallel using `Map` -

```
library(data.table)

x_cols <- grep('^x', names(x), value = TRUE)
y_cols <- grep('^y', names(x), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- sub('x_', '', x_cols)

x[, (new_cols) := Map(function(a, b) ifelse(a == b, 'Y', 'N'), 
                  .SD[, ..x_cols], .SD[, ..y_cols])]

x

#   x_abc y_abc x_pqr y_pqr abc pqr
#1:    A1    A1    A1    B1   Y   N
```